# Can a logistic regression achieve a y=x model?

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm building a logistic regression, and I'm finding it's being outperformed by a simple linear regression.

Let's say, for example, I am trying to predict whether particular future basketball shots will be successful, knowing the person, their history, and some other variables. Out of curiosity, I limited myself to a single variable, the proportion of shots made successfully in the past.

I made 2 models. The first is a logistic regression that trains on the past hit-rate for the person. The 2nd model, which isn't really "fitted", just repeats the past hit-rate as the prediction for the future. This 2nd model seems to do much better. I think this is essentially a `y=x` linear regression model.

I know the shape of the logistic curve is roughly linear for most of the middle of the curve, so I'm a bit surprised that the fitted logistic regression can't find some curve where the relevant parts are linear enough for my data.

Perhaps the most relevant thing is that the "hit-rate" in my problem is almost always under 1%, but it could go as high as 30%. So, I know the curves start to bend as x gets big or small and y approaches 0 or 1, but is there some curve where it's mostly linear from x=0 to x=1?

Comment: Have you tried flexible modeling of your predictor, like with a regression spline or a generalized additive model?

Comment: Repeating the past observation is not a linear regression. It's the "naive" forecast, which is a benchmark that is often surprisingly hard to beat.